# What to do about massive slug size on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

I have a React app created via create-react-app that is my portfolio. It's standard out-of-the-box (not ejected). In the public folder, there are a bunch of my portfolio pieces (interactive websites). Some of the pieces are MASSIVE, so it's not a huge surprise that Heroku chokes (but it never did before this year?).

It looks like the project is building fine, and then I get:

> Compiled slug size: 945.3M is too large (max is 500M).

Followed by:

> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to
> 'https://git.heroku.com/some-project.git'

A portfolio site isn't going to be much good without portfolio pieces, so I'd like find out what I can do about this. Am I going to have to put my pieces up on a different server, or what?

Comment: When you say "portfolio pieces" do you mean media files like images? If so you can store them on e.g. S3 and move them out of the app itself.

Comment: They are each interactive websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Docker image of your app and deploy it on Heroku. AFAIK, Docker images don't have any size limit on Heroku. I have deployed images having a size of around 1.5 GB on Free dyno. This might help: [Deploying with Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker)

Comment: Huh, ok. Can you explain why/how this sidesteps the slug issue?

Comment: Not sure buddy! It might be related to the fact that the underlying stack is changed from Heroku curated stack to container stack.